# VIX and Realised Volatility Scaling

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, vix, variance-swap

I have calculated the VIX implied volatility according to the CBOE Whitepaper:
\begin{equation*}
   \sigma^2 = \frac{2}{T} \left(\sum_i \frac{\Delta K_i}{K_i^2} Q(K_i) e^{rT} \right) - \frac{1}{T} \left( \frac{F_0}{K_0} - 1 \right)^2
   \end{equation*}
on an intraday basis (1-Minute) for two maturities around 30 days and interpolated the 30-Day Implied Volatility from there. I also have calculated the realised variance according to 
\begin{equation}
RV = \sum_{t=0}^T [\ln(P_{t}) - \ln(P_{t-1})]^2
\end{equation}
which I calculated for 1-hour intervals out of minutely recorded prices.

Theoretically the VIX impleid volatility is a forecast for the realised volaitlity in 30 days and one could check this via a simple linear regression. However, I can see from my data immideately that my RV results are in the range of $1\cdot10^{-5}$ and my VIX results in the range of $1\cdot 10^{-2}$. Most likely this is due to the VIX using another scale than the RV (note that I did not annualise my VIX data).

Can anyone point out ot me how to properly scale the VIX or RV so I can continue with the comparison?

Comment: It is a problem of units. RV is usually defined as an average (i.e. the summation of squares is divided by the number of terms in the sum), then it makes sense as a "per period" quantity (per minute in this case). The way you have it (the sum of 60 terms) it is "per hour". I am not sure (=don't remember) what units the CBOE formula is in... if T is expressed in years (i.e. T=1/12) then it is yearly units.